# Entity Framework 6 AsNoTracking<TEntity>(), but for a single entity

Tags: entity-framework

I'm working on a unit of work and repository set-up for Entity Framework, where I want to make sure only changed entities, that have been through an Update method on the repository, are actually saved to the database.

The IQueryable extension, AsNoTracking, makes sure that all entities fetched from the IDbSet are not being tracked, but if I want to read a single entity, by it's primary key (using Find()), there seems to be no way to make sure the entity isn't tracked?

I don't want to Detach/Attach, as that ruins the options to, lazily, fetch complex properties.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing.

`Find` has no `AsNoTracking`. That's because `Find` first tries to find the requested entity in the (tracked!) context cache (the state manager). It goes to the database if it's not there, so for a subsequent second time `Find` it doesn't have to do this roundtrip again.

So, `Find` is all about tracked entities.

Use `Single(OrDefault)` (+ `AsNoTracking`) if you want to get one entity without tracking.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I can't really do that, the repository is generic so there is no way I can get Single or SingleOrDefault to locate the right entity, I need to write an expression, but the generic T isn't know to have an Id property, so I can't do this: ``e => e.Id == id``

Comment: Well, the only thing I can say about that is that architecture is supposed to make life easier. If it doesn't something is wrong. Anyway, it doesn't change the facts about the idea behind `Find`. You could peek in EF's source code to see how they programmed the generic database search part of it.